# Can't import JQuery into TypeScript file

Tags: jquery, typescript

After installing `jquery` and `@types/jquery` I can't seem to get JQuery to work in my typescript file.

If I use:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
$("#test").addClass("className");
```

I get the following error on `$("#test")`:

`TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

If I follow WebStorm's recommended change of changing the import to:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Then no errors show but when trying to compile the file I get the error:

`error TS1192: Module '"C:/Users/Home/Desktop/react/hello-world/node_modules/@types/jquery/index"' has no default export.`

I've looked at a dozen other StackOverFlow posts and nothing has helped. Any ideas?

Comment: If I try something simple like `$.each([],() => {});` I still get $ is undefined?

Comment: seems to work properly with `import $ from 'jquery';`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2sfodn?file=index.ts

Comment: Wanna chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186280/jquery-types

Comment: @Andriy I think it has something to do with React transpilation interacting with Babel

Comment: Never found a solution for this?

Comment: @JuanMendes Afraid not

Comment: If you don't have an answer by the weekend, send me a zip file, and I can try hacking it again. I'll be in that chat for the next 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flag to your `tsconfig` or `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to your script.

Another option would be to try `esModuleInterop` flag.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html
- https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1497
- https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/214

You need TypeScript 1.8.0 or later

Comment: It doesn't work I'm afraid. I was able to reproduce it from a bare `create-react-app`, installing jquery, importing with `import * as $ from 'jquery';` (or any other variation) in `index.tsx` and compiling with `tsc --jsx react-native *tsx`. There's always some error.